# How to Present Text from Another Source?

Tags: discussion, support, formatting

I have sometimes answered questions by copying-and-pasting text from other (disclosed!) sources, then usually italicizing the text to show it's from elsewhere.

In [this thread](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/18023/specific-case-scenario-when-to-apply-for-citizenship), text from elsewhere is shown in a colored box, which does a good job of showing it as imported. How is this type of presentation accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a Markdown blockquote. On the desktop site you can simply select the text you copied, then press the blockquote icon on the toolbar. On mobile or if the toolbar doesn't work you can do that by starting the line with a `>` character. For longer texts all lines (including empty ones) should be marked like this.

Example:

```
> First quote
>
> Second paragraph
```

Will produce:

> First quote
>
> Second paragraph

Generally if you encounter a feature of the posts you can always click the edit button to see the source code of the post where you can see how stuff, like blockquotes were done. There is also a documentation on all markdown features at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/formatting